# LINQ - How to use distinct with order by?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, nhibernate

I want to do a distinct on this:

```
query = from acao in query
  join itemAuditoria in Session.Query<ItemAuditoria>() on acao.Id equals itemAuditoria.Acao.Id
  join auditoria in Session.Query<Auditoria>() on itemAuditoria.Auditoria.Id equals auditoria.Id
  join maquina in Session.Query<Maquina>() on auditoria.Maquina.Id equals maquina.Id
  orderby maquina.Nome, acao.Numero
  select acao;
```

But if I try putting a distinct at the end of the query like this:

```
query = (from acao in query
  join itemAuditoria in Session.Query<ItemAuditoria>() on acao.Id equals itemAuditoria.Acao.Id
  join auditoria in Session.Query<Auditoria>() on itemAuditoria.Auditoria.Id equals auditoria.Id
  join maquina in Session.Query<Maquina>() on auditoria.Maquina.Id equals maquina.Id
  orderby maquina.Nome, acao.Numero
  select acao).Distinct();
```

then I get this error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: As the error says: `ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.`

Comment: right, how do I rewrite this code to achieve that? I can't simply cut and paste the order by after distinct.

Comment: you need to select your objects, then order them after you have disctint the collection

Comment: I don't know how. Show me how.

Comment: remove the orderby clause and add .OrderBy(obj => obj.Nome).ThenBy(obj => obj.Numero) *after* the .Distinct()

Comment: `....).OrderBy(here lambda which must order your objects).Distinct();`

Comment: @Toons33 His `select` isn't selecting out all of the fields that he is going to order by.

Comment: @Servy I think the Distinct extension method in LINQ does not have a query syntax equivalent (see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720945/is-there-a-linq-syntax-way-of-using-distinct]) so he probably needs to add those in the query

Comment: @Toons33 Yes, `Distinct` doesn't have a query syntax equivalent.  Even if it did, it would *still* be a non-trivial problem to solve.  You can't just translate everything to method syntax.  That doesn't solve the problem.  The select needs to come before the `Distinct` or else items that differ only in columns not projected aren't removed, but the select needs to be *after* the `OrderBy` because columns not projected are ordered, and the `OrderBy` needs to be before the `Distinct` because of the above error message.  It's a cyclical dependency graph.

Comment: This is a LINQ to SQL bug and the question is legitimate. No matter whether the query is logically broken L2S may never emit invalid SQL. Because L2S is no longer supported and will not be fixed, you must find a workaround. Play with the query.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the performance impact compared to the answer in OP's comments, but this could be subqueried for readability!

```
query =
    (from distinctAcao in
        (from acao in query
        join itemAuditoria in Session.Query<ItemAuditoria>() on acao.Id equals itemAuditoria.Acao.Id
        join auditoria in Session.Query<Auditoria>() on itemAuditoria.Auditoria.Id equals auditoria.Id
        join maquina in Session.Query<Maquina>() on auditoria.Maquina.Id equals maquina.Id
        select acao).Distinct()
    orderby maquina.Nome, distinctAcao.Numero
    select distinctAcao);
```

---

### edit:

So sorry for overlooking that it didn't compile - it did in my head ;) Corrections on the way!

Because we're doing subquery here, the result of which is a list of `acao` items which don't have a `Nome` field, we cannot sort by it after we leave the subquery. Therefore we can either:

1. Sort inside subquery, then eliminate duplicates.

   ```
   query=(
       from distinctAcao in (
           from acao in query
           join itemAuditoria in Session.Query<ItemAuditoria>() on acao.Id equals itemAuditoria.Acao.Id
           join auditoria in Session.Query<Auditoria>() on itemAuditoria.Auditoria.Id equals auditoria.Id
           join maquina in Session.Query<Maquina>() on auditoria.Maquina.Id equals maquina.Id
           orderby maquina.Nome,acao.Numero
           select acao
       ).Distinct()
       select distinctAcao
   );
   ```

   **Result:** sorted, unique `acao`s list

   **Cons:** first sorting, then filtering might impact performance
2. Return a better, combined object from the subquery, which will expose new fields from joined tables.

   ```
   query2=(
       from distinctMix in (
           from acao in query
           join itemAuditoria in Session.Query<ItemAuditoria>() on acao.Id equals itemAuditoria.Acao.Id
           join auditoria in Session.Query<Auditoria>() on itemAuditoria.Auditoria.Id equals auditoria.Id
           join maquina in Session.Query<Maquina>() on auditoria.Maquina.Id equals maquina.Id
           select new { Id=acao.Id,Numero=acao.Numero,NomeFromMaquina=maquina.Nome }
       ).Distinct()
       orderby distinctMix.NomeFromMaquina,distinctMix.Numero
       select distinctMix
   );
   ```

   **Result:** quickly sorted, unique (`acao`+more) list

   **Cons:** returned object will be of different type than original `query` that was used to iterate `acao`s, so assigning `query=from acao in query select new { /* something else than acao */ };` won't work (hence `query2` in this code example)
3. Use answer from OP's comments :)

### P.S.

This time the code compiles for sure - test code available at https://ideone.com/mDRRle :>

Comment: this code doesn't compile. I can't put "order by" after Distinct(), the compiler complains that "maquina" (after orderby) isn't recognized.

Comment: thanks for the effort, but as I mentioned in the second block of code of my question, if I put an Distinct in the query that used order by, then it's enough to throw an exception at runtime. Maybe it works on EntityFramework, but I'm using NHibernate.

Comment: Of the two solutions in your edit, neither works.  The first one calls `Distinct` after `OrderBy`, and `Distinct` reorders the items.  The second query won't work because you're performing a `Distinct` on additional columns, which means that items that differ only by those columns are being included when they shouldn't be.

Comment: The second remark I didn't realise; as for the first Distinct() didn't change order on my computer nor online compiler so I assumed it preserves it; ergo: this is a well failed attempt at an answer, I apologise for that :C